# Ubuntu + docking station and two external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am trying to setup my working station.
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E495 and a docking station dell, which works fine under Windows with the two external monitors.
With ubuntu I am able to make work only one of the monitors.

```
uname -a
Linux fra 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5920 x 2100, maximum 16384 x 16384
  eDP connected 2560x1440+3360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
  1920x1080     60.01*+
  1680x1050     60.01  
  1280x1024     60.01  
  1440x900      60.01  
  1280x800      60.01  
  1280x720      60.01  
  1024x768      60.01  
  800x600       60.01  
  640x480       60.01  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DisplayPort-1 connected primary 3360x2100+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
   473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.88  
   1280x800      59.88  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      59.88  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

 lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
 05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1)

lshw -c video
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Picasso
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: c1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:80 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0600000-d067ffff
```

Any suggestions on where to start for troubleshooting?
Thanks!

Comment: :( I have no idea how to troubleshoot this at all. Of course with windows the two external monitor work. I hate this and that I am using windows for this reason

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing this: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1576
rebooted and it works!